# In below program only for first two rows it is working and for other rows it is showing incorrect values in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here for the below program i need to print the amt_running_bal from the previous value. but it is not working and showing error. what is the error in the below program.Please provide any solution for this.

```
DECLARE
   total Number := 1000000;
   c_cod_acct_no Char;
   c_amt_txn Number;
   c_cod_drcr Char;
   c_amt_running_bal Number;
   amt_running_bal Number;
   CURSOR c_chnos1 is
   SELECT cod_drcr, amt_txn,amt_running_bal FROM chnos1;
   BEGIN
   OPEN c_chnos1;
   FOR k IN 1..2 LOOP
   FETCH c_chnos1 into c_cod_drcr,c_amt_txn,c_amt_running_bal;
   if  c_cod_drcr = 'C' then
   total := total + c_amt_txn;
   Update chnos1 SET amt_running_bal = total where cod_drcr='C' ;
   elsif
   c_cod_drcr = 'D' then
   total := total - c_amt_txn;
   Update chnos1 SET amt_running_bal = total where cod_drcr='D';
   else
   total := total + c_amt_txn;
   Update chnos1 SET amt_running_bal = total where cod_drcr='C';
   end if;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_chnos1;
   END;
   /
```

Comment: "only for first two rows it is working" - could that be because of `FOR k IN 1..2 LOOP` ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not work as you limit the loop to `k IN 1..2` so it will only read two rows from the cursor and there is no correlation between the row you are reading from the cursor and what you are updating; in fact, you are updating all the rows  `WHERE cod_drcr = 'C'` or  `WHERE cod_drcr = 'D'` and not just the current row. You could fix it by correlating the updates to the current row using the `ROWID` pseudo-column but it is an inefficient solution to use cursors as it will be slow and generate redo/undo log entries for each iteration of the cursor loop.

Instead, do it all in a single `MERGE` statement using an analytic `SUM` and a `CASE` expression:

```sql
MERGE INTO chnos1 dst
USING (
  SELECT rowid AS rid,
         1000000
         + SUM(
             CASE cod_drcr
             WHEN 'C' THEN +amt_txn
             WHEN 'D' THEN -amt_txn
             ELSE 0
             END
           )
           OVER (
             -- Use something like this to update each account
             -- PARTITION BY cod_acct_no ORDER BY payment_date
             -- However, you haven't said how to partition or order the rows so use this
             ORDER BY ROWNUM
           ) AS total
  FROM   chnos1
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET amt_running_bal = src.total;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iS0aFzVy)